# Next.js i18n routing not working for dynamic routes

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Next app which has only two routes: an `index.tsx` and a `[slug].tsx`. The slug route uses `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` to fetch the page from a CMS.

I have enabled internationalized routing by adding this into my `next.config.js`:

```js
i18n: {
  locales: ["en", "fr"],
  defaultLocale: "en",
}
```

The `index` route works fine, if I go to `/` with an `Accept-Language` header of `fr-FR` I get redirected to the `/fr` subroute. What doesn't work is the dynamic route `[slug].tsx`. If I go straight to it, it doesn't redirect me to the fr locale version. And printing my locale in `getStaticProps` shows the default `en` locale, instead of the one computed from my `Accept-Language` header.

I'm aware people usually forget to generate the locale paths in `getStaticPaths` and I don't think that's the problem, here's how I'm generating them:

```
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async ({ locales }) => {
  const clients = await fetchClients();

  const paths = locales
    .map((locale) => clients.map((c) => ({ params: { slug: c.id }, locale })))
    .flat();

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: "blocking",
  };
};
```

Any idea what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question with your entire `getStaticPaths` function?

Comment: @devpolo Ok I did. Although I don't think that's the problem since the redirect won't happen even with `getServerSideProps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic language detection currently only works on the root directory. This [issue comment](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/20657#issuecomment-753253778) and the documentation mention this.

The path generation code looks correct. If a users visits the index page and then navigates to a sub page, they should get re-directed to the correct locale(or default if there's no translation)

You could use middle-ware to manually control this behavior.

First, we need to disable the `localeDetection`.

```js
i18n: {
  locales: ["en", "fr"],
  defaultLocale: "en",
  localeDetection: false,
}
```

Then you can create a new middleware that checks for `Accept-Language` header and re-directs the users to the correct page.

This is a slightly modified version of the example from the Next.js documentation on [prefixing the default locale](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#prefixing-the-default-locale).

```js
// middleware.js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

// you can do this manually or use a library like accept-language-parser
import parser from "accept-language-parser";

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/;

export async function middleware(req) {
  if (
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/_next") ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.includes("/api/") ||
    PUBLIC_FILE.test(req.nextUrl.pathname)
  ) {
    return;
  }

  const acceptLanguageHeader = req.headers.get("accept-language");
  const locale = parser.pick(["fr", "en"], acceptLanguageHeader);

  if (req.nextUrl.locale !== locale) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(`/${locale}${req.nextUrl.pathname}${req.nextUrl.search}`, req.url)
    );
  }
}
```